Is this Athlon64 cpu compatible with my Asus K8N motherboard?
I'm looking for a compatible CPU for an old Asus K8N socket754 main-board. The list from cpu-upgrade.com says these CPUs might be:

ADA3000AIK4BX https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/AMD/Athlon_64/3000+_(rev._E6__BX__1.4V).html
ADA3000AKK4BX https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/AMD/Athlon_64/3000+_(rev._E6__BX__1.35V).html

I found the CPU pictured bellow, for sale locally, but I don't know if it's a supported ones or not. Can you help me? (I tend to believe the picture belongs to a ADA3000AIK4BX (i.e.the first one in the list), but I'd never mapped a cpu-z details sheet to a real CPU.


As usual, the best place to check for compatibility is the vendor's support list. Asus lists the following Athlon 64s as compatible, along with several Semprons:

Athlon 64 2800+
Athlon 64 3000+
Athlon 64 3000+ (Rev E6)
Athlon 64 3200+
Athlon 64 3400+
Athlon 64 3700+

This information is corroborated by cpu-world.

Thank you @JMY100 for you answer. I'd checked the vendor's list and the cpu-world list. My problem is that I don't know whether the CPU (on sale) from the image, is one of those supported Athlon64 3000s. (there are multiple 3000+ CPUs: ADA3000AEP4AP / ADA3000BOX, ADA3000AEP4AR / ADA3000BOX, ADA3000AEP4AX / ADA3000AXBOX, ADA3000AEP5AP, ADA3000AEP5AR, ADA3000AIK4BX / ADA3000BXBOX, ADA3000AKK4BX source: https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-ASUS/K8N.html) Can you please identify the CPU from the image? Is it one from my initial post's list or something from this comments' list? thank you

As far as I’m aware, all socket-compatible Athlon 3000+s are compatible with the K8N.
